# Jersey 2 / JAX-RS Custom Protocol / Port

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

We are looking at upgrading from Jersey 1 / HttpClient 3.1 to Jersey 2 / HttpClient 4.5.12.

We make REST calls to a 3rd party software product uses a unique protocol and port (HTTPS over **sec-http** on **port 8112**) instead of a standard **https/443**.  So an example URL would be HTTPS traffic over `sec-http://myserver:8112/person/1`

**Does anyone know how to set up Jersey 2 / HttpClient 4.x to use a custom protocol and custom port?**

Before we had the following code for Jersey 1 / HttpClient 3.1:

```
  final Protocol protocol = new Protocol("sec-http",
            (ProtocolSocketFactory) new SocketFactory(this.sslContext), 8112);

  Protocol.registerProtocol(protocolScheme, protocol);
```

For the life of me, I can't get this to work in Jersey 2 / HttpClient 4.5.12. The `Protocol` class is gone.

Here's what I've tried:

```
  LayeredConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(this.sslContext); 


  Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> r = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
       .register("sec-http", sslsf) // how do I specify a custom port?!  
       .build();


  PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager httpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(r);

  ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
  clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
  clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, httpClientConnectionManager);
  clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.DISABLE_COOKIES, Boolean.FALSE);
  clientConfig.register(new JacksonFeature());


 Client client =  ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                     .withConfig(clientConfig)
                     .build();
```